# Regular Expression to catch a sequence of letter and digit but containing minimum 3 letters ? how to do?

Tags: php, regex

I have to do a regular expression in PHP which catch in a text the strings that contain only uppercase letters, digits, or underscore. 
Exemple : `THIS_STUFF`, `THIS_2_STUFF`, `ONE_MORE_STUFF_2_CATCH` etc...
It works well with : `/[A-Z0-9_]/`

BUT, I want to catch the sequences that are only :
- minimum 5 chars ==> `/[A-Z0-9_]{5,}/`
- AND containing min 3 uppercase letters ==> ????

Have you any ideas ?

Thanks !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> AND containing min 3 uppercase letters ==> ????

Use a [positive lookahead assertion](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html)  at the start for this.

```
^(?=(?:[^A-Z\n]*[A-Z]){3})[A-Z0-9_]{5,}$
```

OR

```
\b(?=(?:[^A-Z]*[A-Z]){3})[A-Z0-9_]{5,}+\b
```

[DEMO](https://regex101.com/r/hE9iF2/5)

Comment: Thanks ! I'm gonna try it.

Comment: please recheck the regex.

Comment: I recheck but it's not what I need. If you look at here (https://regex101.com/r/zE3iK5/1) you'll see that your regex catch strings that shouldn't be caught... Thanks anyway !

Comment: @DamFa add a newline character inside the negated charcater class https://regex101.com/r/zE3iK5/2 , since you want to match a string which has no newline character then `\n` inside the negated class is unnecessary. That's why i won't to put that inside the negated char class. And also `TES_123` is a match because it contains atleast 3 uppercase letters and `_`, digits. Total length greater than 5. Satisfied.

Comment: Mhh... what a "newline character" can change to this issue ? I don't want to catch strings like "123456" and the regex will catch it anyway ? no ?

Comment: I've re-arranged it and the correct answer is : `(\b(?=(?:[^A-Z]*[A-Z]){3})[A-Z0-9_]{5,}+\b)`. Check demo here : https://regex101.com/r/kP3nM8/1